# C# WPF All overlapping controls receive mouse event on overlapping portion

Tags: c#, wpf, mouseevent, overlapping

I have a canvas that contains several UserControls that can be overlapped by each other. When the user clicks at overlapping portion, I want all UserControls that contain that portion to receive mouse event (not only the top one as default). As I know, Event Routing Strategys like Tunnel and Bubble only works for Logical Tree, but all my controls are sibling and they only have Z-order relationship. 
Is there a proper way to do what I am trying to do?

Comment: I suggest you to create a single command for this click event and then bind the same command for the click event of each of the controls that you need. Same command will be reused but you will have to mention it wherever you want to catch the click event.

Comment: @RavirajPalvankar Thank you for your suggestion, but it does seem to match my expectation. In my case, I want every UserControl to receive its own Click event and execute its own job when I click somewhere on their overlapping part.

Comment: Then again - write a single command for all, have an enum created for each user control's name or any identifier. Pass the enum value in the command parameter and inside the execute command method write a switch case based on the parameter and then call the respective jobs for each case.